# Perl - retrieve values from a hash of hashes

Tags: perl, hash

How do we retrieve the values of keys in a Hash of Hashes in Perl?
I tried to use the keys function. I wanted to remove the duplicates and then sort them, which i could 
do using the `uniq` and `sort` functions. Am I missing anything?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

sub ids {
    my ($data) = @_;

    my @allID = keys %{$data};

    my @unique = uniq @allID;
    foreach ( @unique ) {
        @allUniqueID = $_;
    }

    my @result = sort{$a<=>$b}(@allUniqueId);
    return @result;
}

my $data = {
    'first' => {
        'second' => {
            'third1' => [
                { id => 44, name => 'a', value => 'aa' },
                { id => 48, name => 'b', value => 'bb' },
                { id => 100, name => 'c', value => 'cc' }
            ],
            id => 19
        },
        'third2' => [
            { id => 199, data => 'dd' },
            { id => 40, data => 'ee' },
            { id => 100, data => { name => 'f', value => 'ff' } }
        ],
        id => 55
    },
    id => 1  
};

# should print “1, 19, 40, 44, 48, 55, 100, 199”
print join(', ', ids($data)) . "\n";
```

I know it's incomplete, but I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This routine will recursively walk the data structure and pull out all of the values that correspond to a hash key `id`, without sorting the results or eliminating duplicates:

```
sub all_keys {
    my $obj = shift;

    if (ref $obj eq 'HASH') {
        return map {
            my $value = $obj->{$_};
            $_ eq 'id' ? $value : ref $value ? all_keys($value) : ();
        } keys %$obj;

    } elsif (ref $obj eq 'ARRAY') {
        return map all_keys($_), @$obj;

    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

To do the sorting/eliminating, just call it like:

```
my @ids = sort { $a <=> $b } uniq(all_ids($data));
```

(I assume the `uniq` routine is defined elsewhere.)

Comment: Uniq was a built in function which I used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version of the recursive approach

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub ids {
   my ($data) = @_;

   my @retval;
   if (ref $data eq 'HASH') {
      push @retval, $data->{id} if exists $data->{id};
      push @retval, ids($_) for values %$data;
   }
   elsif (ref $data eq 'ARRAY') {
      push @retval, ids($_) for @$data;
   }
   @retval;
}

my $data = {
    'first' => {
        'second' => {
            'third1' => [
                { id => 44, name => 'a', value => 'aa' },
                { id => 48, name => 'b', value => 'bb' },
                { id => 100, name => 'c', value => 'cc' }
            ],
            id => 19
        },
        'third2' => [
            { id => 199, data => 'dd' },
            { id => 40, data => 'ee' },
            { id => 100, data => { name => 'f', value => 'ff' } }
        ],
        id => 55
    },
    id => 1  
};

my @ids = sort { $a <=> $b  } ids($data);
print join(', ', @ids), "\n";
```

**output**

```
1, 19, 40, 44, 48, 55, 100, 100, 199
```

---

**Update**

A large chunk of the code in the solution above is there to work out how to extract the list of values from a data reference. Recent versions of Perl have an experimental facility that allows you to use the `values` operator on both hashes and arrays, and also on references ro both, so if you're running version 14 or later of Perl 5 and are comfortable disabling *experimental* warnings, then you can write `ids` like this instead

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.014;

sub ids {
   my ($data) = @_;
   return unless my $type = ref $data;

   no warnings 'experimental';
   if ( $type eq 'HASH' and exists $data->{id} ) {
      $data->{id}, map ids($_), values $data;
   }
   else {
      map ids($_), values $data;
   }
}
```

The output is identical to that of the previous solution